# Battle of bits Perl and Oracle

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

My machine is 64 bit, Perl is 64 bit, but Oracle is 32 bit
how can i connect to database install DBD DBI module that connects to 32 bit oracle

I cannot install 64 bit Oracle

Comment: If you can't install 64-bit Oracle, can you install 32-bit perl?

Comment: "*Oracle is 32*" server or client? Do not care about server platform, the only important point is platform of Oracle client libs. Download and unzip 64bit Oracle InstantClient.

Comment: Correct - use a 64 bit driver (which doesn't care what bitness of Oracle it connects to since it is not an "in process" connection)